# Adding custom functions to Lead "control bar" drop down list

Tags: lightning-experience, leads, custom

Apologies if the question title is vague, I'm unsure what the correct name for this particular object/control is. I've attached an image to demonstrate more clearly.

[image: Drop Down List]

The "Send SMS" is a custom function included in a managed package which was configured for us previously - I'm looking to add other functions (some would be newly built custom ones) to this drop down list on the "Lead" object. Where can this be configured?

Comment: These custom functions are called "Actions". They are available in the Object manager (Setup), "Buttons/Actions" tab after having chosen the object (Lead in your case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called "Actions".

Go to Setup  >  Object Manager  >  Lead  > Page Layout  >  Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions.

Add/Remove whichever actions you want.